# Why does Paul put his cold drink on some woman's back at the party in Breakfast at Tiffany's?

Tags: plot-explanation, breakfast-at-tiffanys

In the party scene in *Breakfast at Tiffany's*, Holly starts a fire by accident and Paul gestures for her to put it out. After the fire is dealt with, Paul puts his cold drink next to some woman's back, causing her to jerk away and yell.

This has always bugged me out because I don't understand why he would do that.

Comment: Also, why would the police care so much about a simple noise complaint that they'd send two squad cars, and why would said squad cars use their sirens on an empty street?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's been trying to reach Holly but the crush of people have blocked his path and the two women in front of him are ignoring him and he can't get through.

So he touches a cold glass to the woman's bare back so she will react by jumping forwards and get out of his way.

Plus, it's funny!☺

Comment: The scene with the fire and the back-touching don't seem to exist, either in the source novel or the script. I think it's all just intended to show that this is a swinging party with crazy stuff happening